# Attempting to call a class constructer in main method so I can create a report card

Tags: c#

Im trying to create a report card class and return a letter grade to main. I used a class constructor for the report card as the actual report card must be a class. In the event an invalid value is entered it will return an argument exception an prompt the user to try again. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
class StudentGradeDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        char lettergrade = new ReportCard();
    }

    class StudentGrades
    {
        public string studentName;
        public double midtermGrade;
        public double finalExamGrade;
        public char letterGrade;


        public char ReportCard(string studentName, double midtermGrade, double finalExamGrade)
        {
            char[] letterGrade = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F' };
            Console.WriteLine("Enter midterm grade");
            midtermGrade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
           if(midtermGrade >= 0 && midtermGrade <= 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter final exam grade");
                finalExamGrade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (finalExamGrade >= 0 && midtermGrade <= 100)
                {
                    double gradeAverage = ((midtermGrade + finalExamGrade) / 2);
                    if(gradeAverage >= 90 && gradeAverage <= 100)
                    {
                        return letterGrade[0];
                    }
                    else if(gradeAverage >= 80 && gradeAverage <= 90)
                    {
                        return letterGrade[1];
                    }
                    else if(gradeAverage >= 70 && gradeAverage <= 80)
                    {
                        return letterGrade[2];
                    }
                    else if(gradeAverage >= 60 && gradeAverage <= 70)
                    {
                        return letterGrade[3];
                    }
                    else if(gradeAverage < 60)
                    {
                        return letterGrade[4];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        throw new System.ArgumentException();
                    }
                    catch (ArgumentException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Grades must be between 0 - 100");
                        return letterGrade[0];
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    throw new System.ArgumentException();
                }
                catch (ArgumentException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Grades must be between 0 - 100");
                    return letterGrade[0];
                }
            }
            return letterGrade[0];
        }
    }
}
```

The error that returns is: `Error  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ReportCard' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: `char lettergrade = (new StudentGrades()).ReportCard();`

Comment: @mjwills

Compiler Error:
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'studentName' of 'StudentGradeDemo.StudentGrades.ReportCard(string, double, double)'

Comment: `ReportCard` takes 3 parameters (studentName, midtermGrade, finalExamGrade). You need to pass them in when you call it.

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/c-sharp-class-object.html

Answer (score 1):

This first thing you need to do is create an instance of the `StudentGrades` class. This will allow you to access the `ReportCard` method, as it's a method of the class. (see #1). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods

Next, if you look at the `ReportCard` method it takes 3 parameters: studentName, midtermGrade, finalGrade. These values MUST be passed into the method when you call it (see #2). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters

```
static void Main()
{
    var studentGrades = new StudentGrades(); // #1

    Console.WriteLine("Enter student name");
    var studentName = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter midterm grade");
    var midtermGrade = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter final exam grade");
    var finalExamGrade = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    var lettergrade = studentGrades.ReportCard(studentName, midtermGrade, finalExamGrade); // #2

    Console.WriteLine($"{studentName}'s grade is an {lettergrade}");
}
```

**Update**: If you want to read input from the user, read in each line and assign to appropriate variable to pass in. I took this code from your ReportCard method, so you need to make sure to remove it from there. Also, you should be doing the appropriate type checking and handling for midterm and finalExamGrade. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: the 3 parameters passed to Report Card must be entered by the user so they are not constant

Comment: @Argos Then request user input for them? It looks like you're already doing this to some extent in your method, so it's clear that you know how to do it. That said, I'm not sure why you're overwriting your method parameters without using them.

Comment: @ArgosDave move the user input request to Main. Get both values, and pass them in from there. (see update)

Answer (score 0):

This is how to solve your problem:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char lettergrade = StudentGrades.ReportCard();
    }
}

public static class StudentGrades
{
    public static char ReportCard()
    {
        char[] letterGrade = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F' };
        Console.WriteLine("Enter midterm grade");
        double midtermGrade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (midtermGrade >= 0 && midtermGrade <= 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter final exam grade");
            double finalExamGrade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (finalExamGrade >= 0 && midtermGrade <= 100)
            {
                double gradeAverage = ((midtermGrade + finalExamGrade) / 2);
                if (gradeAverage >= 90 && gradeAverage <= 100)
                {
                    return letterGrade[0];
                }
                else if (gradeAverage >= 80 && gradeAverage <= 90)
                {
                    return letterGrade[1];
                }
                else if (gradeAverage >= 70 && gradeAverage <= 80)
                {
                    return letterGrade[2];
                }
                else if (gradeAverage >= 60 && gradeAverage <= 70)
                {
                    return letterGrade[3];
                }
                else if (gradeAverage < 60)
                {
                    return letterGrade[4];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    throw new System.ArgumentException();
                }
                catch (ArgumentException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Grades must be between 0 - 100");
                    return letterGrade[0];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentException();
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Grades must be between 0 - 100");
                return letterGrade[0];
            }
        }
        return letterGrade[0];
    }
}
```